# Instruments CLI error: Failed to load template

Tags: instruments, xcode9

I'm getting an error when trying to use the File Activity template with Instruments. I do:

```
instruments -t "File Activity" -D ./traces -p $my_pid &
```

and I get the following error:

```
instruments[33281]: [error] Failed to load template 'file:///Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/templates/File%20Activity.tracetemplate':
    There is a missing instrument in this document that can't be recovered.
```

Has anyone else has luck with this template? Is it possibly no longer supported?